# Badge is not shown on profile

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, necromancer-badge

I've been awarded a silver badge (Necromancer) but the badge is not shown on my profile; is this a bug?

Comment: You don't see dead badges? http://stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer?userid=144408

Comment: I mean for meta stackoverflow badges http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/132194/shahjapan here in top it shows shahjapan 199 1 silver 6 bronze but on my profile page only 6 badges are displayed

Comment: This is most likely the same issue as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61603/where-is-the-necromancer-badge). It may be that you had received downvotes on an answer, but a bug that caused downvotes to cease existence triggered you to get the badge. A subsequent cleanup would result in destroying the badge when the downvotes return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also cannot see that badge in your profile, and you don't appear in [the list of Necromancer winners](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer).  How do you know it was awarded to you?  Did you get a notification bar at the top of MSO?

Sometimes it takes a few hours or even days for the system to award an earned badge.  Normally, I'd say that if you were tracking the criteria (Answered a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more.) manually, you might just need to wait a bit.

In your case, though, I'm not sure you've met the criteria.  (I'm also not sure you haven't.)  I only see one answer for you, posted Feb 23 for a question asked Dec 4.  That's >60 days, so the first criterion is met.  Its score is 3 (+5/-2).  It's possible that its net score was 5 at one point, but if it was downvoted to below 5 before the Necromancer award script was run, you wouldn't get the badge.

Comment: The presence of a silver "1" is the main indication. This is looking more and more similar to the other thread I linked, right down to a 5/-2 score on the same question. That user also had a silver badge listed in the flair yet not on the profile, but shortly after posting the question that silver badge disappeared.

Comment: @Grace, yeah, your comment appeared while I was typing up this answer (it took me a while).  You're likely right.